# SonarQube doesn't send notification to Discord webhook

Tags: sonarqube, discord, webhooks, sonarqube-scan

I want notification on my discord app after completing every scan in sonarqube. I have tried to configured my discord webhook URL in sonarqube webhook option but it getting 400 error code after scanning the code and not sending notification.

Steps i tried :

1. Created webhook URL from my discord chennel.
2. Configured that webhook URL in `sonarqube > Administration > Configuration > Webhooks`.
3. Run code scan So that it send notification to configured webhook.

But i am getting below error.

`Error` :

```
Last delivery of Spidey Bot

Response: 400
Duration: 186ms
Payload: .....
```

[Discord webohook screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJ5Gp.png)

[SonarQube Error screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6Iix.png)

Comment: The 400 response refers to a `bad request` so, it's possible that the format of the payload being sent is in some way invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out, request body format which SonarQube sends to Discord is not acceptable. It leads to bad request error. Below is logged response from Discord,

> {
>       "message": "Cannot send an empty message",
>       "code": 50006
>   }

To successfully post the message it must be in the specific format documented https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook

The solution to this could be a mediatory URL which parses the request body and hits Discord Webhook with excepted body params.